# Video Cut/trim crashes using Intel media-for-mobile sample

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, intelinde

I am using Intel media-for-mobile sample (https://github.com/INDExOS/media-for-mobile) to Trim/Cut video. However when I try for video trim and click start button it gives me an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

with logcat red error as:
A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.

```
[OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -1010
```

Codec reported an error.

```
(omx error 0x80001001, internalError -1010)
```

Can any body help me to get rid of this issue. I spend two days on this issue but could not figure it out.

Comment: You say you've spent two days on this issue, what have you tried? avoid other users from wasting time on something that you may have tried and failed

Comment: The issue seems to be associated with video Width, video Height, video Bit Rate, video Frame Rate. As it works fine for 1280 * 720 resolution but crashes for all other especially for portrait mode videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discussion is continued here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/543502

INDE M4M does not support input MPEG-4 video. Need to use H.264