# Fast android decoding/encoding media extractor

Tags: android, encoding, compression, decoding, mediaextractor

I'm following code from [MediaMuxer video compression (change resolution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943121/mediamuxer-video-compression-change-resolution) and https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java.

For a one minute video on my HTC One M8, it takes 40 seconds to fully compress to a smaller file size. On my Sony Z3 however, it takes a full two minutes to compress its one minute video. Is there a more performant way to do this compression?

Whatsapp as an example seems to compress the same video (one minute) in one minute and twenty seconds.